# JS Navigate after recieve a redirect response

Tags: javascript, redirect, navigation, fetch, service-worker

I'm implementing an HTTP service on a backend that should return a `302 FOUND` response with a `location` header.

This service is called by a javascript front-end.

I'm currently using the Fetch API to send my request to the service. I've seen in the documentation that with this API it's not possible to set up the `mode: navigate`.

> navigate
> A mode for supporting navigation. The navigate value is intended to be used only by HTML navigation. A navigate request is created only while navigating between documents.

So, when I execute my request, I get a redirect intercepted by the browser, which sends a request to the url present in the response location. But even though the redirection takes place, the navigation doesn't.

The browser needs explicit instructions to perform a navigation redirect instead of silently following the redirect.

Is it possible to tell the browser that it must navigate to the location url, either by configuring the headers in the response or by configuring the initial request?

Comment: I think Fetch follows redirects automatically. So the AJAX response will be whatever the final destination returns.

Comment: When you call an API, it's supposed to return data that the client can use. If the client application needs to navigate, that's done by assigning to `window.location` in the client. The API doesn't cause the client to navigate automatically.

Comment: When the response status is a redirection status (3xx), the response is not processed by the client code but intercepted by the browser before the javascript can even read it.

Comment: That's what I meant by it follows redirects automatically. It will go to that URL, and return its response as the response to `fetch()`. It doesn't redirect the web page, since fetch is for returning data to JS.

Comment: It is the browser that will perform the redirection. As I was saying, the redirection is carried out correctly, i.e. another http request is made but with the header `Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors` instead of `Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate`. So I get a blob-readable text/html in my JS. But I don't want to retrieve a blob, I want to be redirected to this html page.

Comment: You can't be redirected by fetch automatically. The only time the browser navigates to the target of a redirect is when it was already navigating to the page that sent the redirect.

Comment: Oh Ok ! Thanks for this information, but is it possible to manage this in any other way than with a Fetch method? I need to send a request of the type "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary" via a POST method and then be redirected...

Comment: And do you know why navigate with the fetch API is forbidden? Is it a security issue?

Comment: Just submit the form. Fetch is used when you don't want the page to reload.

Comment: It's just not what AJAX is for. AJAX is for calling APIs, not navigating.

Comment: The problem with sending forms directly is that it's very difficult, if not impossible, to process the errors returned by the API. That's why I looked into using AJAX with Fetch or XHR or even HttpClient from angular because my front is in Angular.  But I think I'll have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Barmar mentioned, AJAX (i.e. Fetch, XHR and all the libraries resulting from these methods) was not created for navigate. So it's not possible to navigate automatically following a redirect response (3xx) using AJAX.

In my example my REST service manages user authentication.

The aim is to have an automatic redirection linked to a 302 and to handle errors when the user logs in.

To achieve this, I've created 2 endpoints: the first checks the user's credentials and stores a session cookie. The second checks whether this session cookie is present in the request and returns a 302.
On the front end, I call the first service with the fetch API. Then I can handle connection errors, and if there are no errors I call the second service via `window.location.url`.